# How can I avoid fish/deer extinction?

Tags: banished

I've built some hunting lodges and I'm looking at constructing another nearby. How can I know how much is too much for the local deer population? So far, I've decided on the simple guideline that no two hunting lodges should overlap, but four hunters/lodge is perfectly safe, but I've not actually found any evidence to suggest that this is safe.

I'm not looking to fish yet but I will be, so I'd also like to know the same thing for fish- how can I know how much is sustainable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have personally come to the conclusion that overlapping is bad, anything else is fine and dandy. As a test I had ten fishing huts along a river, but none of them overlapped, and they all produced (roughly) the same amount of food, showing no decline as the river went on.

As soon as I overlapped them however, it seemed to decrease the production instantly. As such, your best bet is to simply spread everything out to make certain they do not overlap.

Also, make sure you do not chop down the forests around your hunting lodges, as the forest is important for its productionrate.

Comment: This confirms my suspicious as well, but I'm curious over how many seasons you performed testing on? Just one or two, or did you leave the fishing huts up for a few years?

Comment: They were up for 3 years before population collapsed and fishers started dropping screwing up the rest of the results.

Comment: Does that mean if you have two overlapping fishing docks at the "top" of the river, it affects a (non-overlapped) fishing dock at the "bottom" of the river?

Comment: Is this decrease in productivity permenant, or does it recover if you stop work at one of the overlapping docks?

Comment: 1) No, it only affects the two that are overlapping
2) No, only as long as both are being worked. It feels to me like basically one 'bit' generates x fish. If two overlap then only one can use the overlapping part.

Comment: You wouldn't expect to see the *total* number of fish drop in that scenario, which is certainly not what extinction would represent- extinction would be a drop in the total number of fish being harvested, as opposed to simply not increasing.

Comment: 22 years in, and the deer are more plentiful than the citizens on my colony.

Answer (score 4):

Theik is correct, but I just wanted to add to clarify: Fish/Deer will not go extinct, even if hunting lodges or fishing huts overlap. As soon as you destroy the overlapping building, the first building's production should go back to what it was before the overlap. Fish and Deer production are constant and based entirely on other factors (which seems to be amount of favorable land, water tiles for fishing for example).

From the "Myths" section of the FAQ on the Banished Wiki:

> "You need to worry about overhunting/fish stocks depleting over
>   time/soil degradation from farming" - these features apparently never
>   made it into the final game. However, overlapping hunting
>   cabins/fishing docks will reduce average catch per citizen.

Source: http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Tips

Comment: Just to be sure: I can use the same seeds on a crop field all the time without any degradation?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many fields of the same crop as you want. However, pestilence can jump from field to field of the same crop, so if they are nearby then you risk losing your entire food supply with one pestilence. Same goes for animals - animal herds of the same type shouldn't be near each other.

Comment: Thank you. Is 'pestilence' the same as 'infestation' (http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Crop#Infestation)? (Sorry, English is not my first language).

Comment: Ah yes my mistake, it is indeed the same thing (I used the wrong term.)